# In this scenario, how to frame a common function and parameterize casting?

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

These are the 2 sets of activities :

```
        //#1
        List<object> AFilterObject = A_List.SelectedList;
        List<A> AFilters = new List<A>();
        foreach (Aitem in AFilterObject )
        {
            //Do activity X
        }
        //#2
        List<object> BFilterObj = B_List.SelectedList;
        List<B> payopFilters = new List<B>();
        foreach (B item in BFilterObj )
        {
            //Do same activity X            }
```

As you can see both the set of activities are common except for the type involved.
How can I write a method with 2 parameters - filterObject, Type - so that I can use this method in a common manner?

To make myself clearer, the final objective is:

```
CommonMethod(List<object> x, Type y???) { //cast x to type y then do some stuff }

//so that I can call
CommonMethod(BFilterObj ,B); 
//or
CommonMethod(AFilterObj ,A);
```

Comment: I'd like to know what's your implementation of the relationship between types, e.g., A and AFilterObj, B and BFilterObj, etc. That will reveal for caveats we need to take into account.

Answer (score 3):

Use a generic method:

```
public void ApplyFilters<T>(List<object> x)
{
   ...
}
```

You may need to apply some *constraints* to T so that you can do what you need to in the method. For example:

```
public void ApplyFilters<T>(List<object> x) 
    where T : class. ISomeInterface
{
   ...
}
```

You would then call it by specifying the type as a *type argument*:

```
ApplyFilters<A>(AFilterObj);
ApplyFilters<B>(BFilterObj);
```

If you don't know the type until execution time, that becomes somewhat harder - you have to call the method with reflection. Let me know if this is the case - but you don't want to do that unless you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

If they have a common interface or base type, you can do this:

```
void DoActivities<TItem>(IList<TItem> filterObject) where TItem : SomeBaseType
{
    foreach (SomeBaseType item in filterObject)
    {
        item.DoActivity(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

If they don't have anything in common, you could do this:

```
void DoActivities<TItem>(IList<TItem> filterObject, Action<TItem> activity)
{
    foreach (TItem item in filterObject)
    {
        activity(item);
    }
}
```

Then you could pass a delegate/lambda expression:

```
List<SomeClass> items = new List<SomeClass>();
// ...
DoActivities(items, (item) => item.SomeClassMethod(/* ... */));
```